# Add an AND condition inside an OR condition

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have a collection that I have to filter according to multiple strings in one field. The trick is that one of the possible values in that field needs to be picked only if another field's value meets a certain condition.
For example:

```
$this->addFieldToFilter(
  'my_field1', 
  array(
    'val1', |
    'val2', |  <--- This is the OR part
    'val3', |
    'val4 AND my_field2 like 'my_field2_val' // <-- This is the tricky part
   )
);
```

Can any of you guys help me?
PS: My collection is a flat one not EAV.

Answer (score 4):

## Works only for EAV collections - I think.

You can add ANDs and ORs like this:

## OR

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=> 'someattribute','like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute'=> 'otherattribute','like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute'=> 'anotherattribute','like' => 'value'),
    )
);
```

## AND inside OR

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array( // AND
            array('attribute'=> 'someattribute','like' => 'value'),
            array('attribute'=> 'otherattribute','like' => 'value'),
        ),
        array('attribute'=> 'anotherattribute','like' => 'value'),
    )
);
```

So just stack the arrays.

Comment: I have the following:
$this->addFieldToFilter(
 array(
   array('attribute' => 'event_code', array('eq'=>'val1')),
   array('attribute' => 'event_code', array('eq'=>'val2')),
 )
)
And the resulting query is something like:
SELECT ..... AND (Array = '') LIMIT 50

Comment: The collection is flat. Could that be why I cannot stack the arrays?

Comment: @DenisR Instead of `array('eq'=>'val1')` it should be just `'eq'=>'val1'`.

Comment: Thanks @marius but still not working. the generated query is the same.

Comment: I think this only works on EAV collections. Please try with addAttributeToFilter. If this is not available due to flat, you are out of luck afaik.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt, I already tried it and it throws an error. 
I am really amazed and disappointed of how restricted is the magento ORM.

Comment: yep. I know this feeling. The alternative is `$collection->getSelect()->doWhateverYouWantWithThisZend_Db_SelectObject`

Comment: Thanks @FabianBlechschmidt, I thinks that's my only solution. Either that or write the query by hand.

Comment: Be very careful when you write it by hand and make sure to not add a SQL injection issue.